# One of my project on Codepen doesn’t work anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codepen

As stated in topic name one of my projects don’t work as supposed to anymore. It worked last night. The only thing that is of semi help is removing all javascript code. Commenting out all code doesn’t help, only removal of said code.

Code itself isn’t anything special, just some smooth scrolling and couple animations. Checking in codepen doesnt produce any errors, neither in browser console. What can it be? I noticed codepen has been changed, maybe something they did messed up my project? All my other projects with JS code work fine but not this one:[Pen](https://codepen.io/codename11/pen/PBzmoM)

And here is js code:

```
var crock = 0;
var hash = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navbar a").on("click", function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();

      hash = this.hash;

      $("html, body").animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        },
        800,
        function() {
          window.location.hash = hash;
        }
      );
    }
  });

  if (!$("#menu").is(":checked")) {
    console.log("unchecked");
    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  }

  $("#menu").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#menu").is(":checked")) {
      $(".animated:even").addClass("bounceInRight");
      $(".animated:odd").addClass("bounceInLeft");
      console.log("checked");
      $(".container").animate(
        {
          width: "100%"
        },
        "slow",
        "swing"
      );

      $("section").animate(
        {
          "padding-right": "30px"
        },
        "slow",
        "swing"
      );
    } else {
      if ($(".animated").hasClass("bounceInRight")) {
        $(".animated").removeClass("bounceInRight");
      }

      if ($(".animated").hasClass("bounceInLeft")) {
        $(".animated").removeClass("bounceInLeft");
      }
    }
  });

  $("#main-doc").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });

  $("[href='#Introduction_to_PHP']").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });

  $("[href='#Basics_things_about_PHP']").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });

  $("[href='#Data_types']").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });

  $("[href='#Variable_scope']").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });

  $("[href='#Loops']").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });

  $("[href='#Functions_in_PHP']").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });

  $("[href='#Reference']").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu").prop("checked", false);

    $(".container").animate(
      {
        width: "75%"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );

    $("section").animate(
      {
        "padding-right": "0px"
      },
      "slow",
      "swing"
    );
  });
});
```

[image: This is how it looks like messed up]

Comment: I wish we could have `meta codepen` site :>

Comment: Whats not working? Tried it after uncommenting the js and from what I can see its working.. Try a diff browser..

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone It sort of "defective" as in this pic above. Button at top left corner just makes container wider ... It doesnt open menu at all. Plus content in header tag goes out of bounds(in the upper left corner) for all containers.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Small correction: It doesn't work when Codepen is in "Full Page" mode.In editor view works, even if you make height high as possible. And i also tried on phone and ancient laptop that i have.

Comment: Just found out something: Even if all js code is deleted and if just press enter to go newline in js section, project button and css goes haywire as if uncommented js code is present. Really peculiar.

Comment: Different browsers, cleaning cache, different devices ... I tried it all. Whomever be so kind to post screenshot of it working if just to put my  mind at ease.

Comment: Tried it in "Debug Mode" also, works there, but not in "Full Page" mode(still).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, something's wrong with codepen not loading bourbon-neat when on full page.
So i just uploaded compiled scss code.